# Mysql query can't remove word from query

Tags: php, sql, cpu-word

```
$terms = $db->GetAll("SELECT `TITLE`, `HITS` FROM `{$tables['category']['name']}` WHERE `STATUS` = '2' && `TITLE` NOT LIKE '%and%' ORDER BY `HITS` DESC LIMIT 0, $limit");
```

Trying to remove the word "and" from MYSQL query.

In my database I have:
Business and Economy
Sports and Recreation

I want my query to display Business, Economy, Sports, Recreation without the word "and" included.

The query not working exactly how I thought it would instead it is removing any TITLE with the word "and" in it.

Comment: Don't do this in mySQL. Fetch it from the database and do it in PHP

Answer (score 1):

`` $terms = $db->GetAll("SELECT REPLACE(`TITLE`, 'and', '') AS `TITLE`, `HITS` FROM `{$tables['category']['name']}` WHERE `STATUS` = '2' ORDER BY `HITS` DESC LIMIT 0, $limit"); ``

Comment: This will return `Business  Economy` and `Sports  Recreation`. You'll still need to process it.

Comment: how did that work? It replaces `and` with nothing, so you have no commas after Business or Sports

Comment: I'm using the query in a Tag Cloud. And before it would tag "and" as one of the biggest tag words.

Comment: I didn't include all the code so perhaps that is why it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(title,'and',','), hits
FROM {$tables['category']['name']}` 
WHERE STATUS = '2'
ORDER BY hits DESC
LIMIT 0
```

Comment: I didn't intend to remove titles that contained "and" even though the code was written that way. I just wanted to exclude "and" from Business and Economy and Sports and Recreation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = $db->GetAll("SELECT replace(`TITLE`, 'and', ',') as title `HITS` FROM `{$tables['category']['name']}` WHERE `STATUS` = '2' ORDER BY `HITS` DESC LIMIT 0, $limit");
```

Untested, but should work. The [replace function is documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).